# Running into race condition issue with vanilla javascript

Tags: javascript, shopify, liquid, race-condition

**No jQuery answers**

I have this nice little script:

```js
var addToCartButton = document.querySelector("[data-ab-testing]");
addToCartButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
  if (addToCartButton.dataset.abTesting === "true") {
    var ch = "?";
    if (String(document.URL).includes("?")) {
      ch = "&";
    }
    window.top.location.href = `${document.URL}${ch}preview_theme_id=`;
  }
  document.querySelector(".Drawer__Content").submit();
});
```

Here is the backstory:

We have a shopify site and we are trying to do some A/B testing, so we have a cookie set to keep people in theme A or theme B. Simple enough? The issue is that when you get to the checkout page of any theme other than theme A, a little bar goes at the bottom of the screen to let you know you are in a testing theme. So to get rid of that we added this script to throw you back over to the correct theme no matter what theme you are cookied under.

Here is what the script does:

The script grabs the cart button, checks to see if ab testing is set to true (we use dynamic liquid code to set it to true or false), and then (if true) append the "preview_theme_id=" to everything.

Here is the issue:

We get a race condition between resetting the url of window.top.location.href and the .submit(). I dont know if i could do some sort of async await/promise architecture i'm honestly not familiar with the page lifecycle enough to know where to go with this outside of just looking for something in the shopify api and rewriting the logic from scratch to pull in the form data and somehow fake the url. I shouldn't run into any cross site issues but I was wondering if anyone had any ideas or article i could use that may help before i attempt to completely rework this.

Comment: If you are changing the window location, why do you need to submit the form?  Changing the url is going to cause a page transfer.

Comment: How are customers moving to the checkout page? Is it by submitting a cart form? If so, you could make the cart form's `action` attribute point to your live theme, perhaps?

Comment: Let me make sure and get back to you but this might be the answer. if it is could you make an official answer so i can mark it as such?